# gob not decoding as expected

Tags: go, gob

Here is my playground where I am trying to serialize a list of structures and read back from the file.

https://play.golang.org/p/8x0uciOd1Sq

I was expecting the object to be decoded successfully. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Export](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) the field names by capitalizing the first letter.

```
type REntry struct {
      Key         string
      Value       []string
 }
```

The gob package and other similar packages ignore unexported fields.